# Calling ms Access function from ASP.NET or any other Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ms-access

I am trying to call a Microsfot Access function from ASP.NET web applicaton in Visual Studio. I am able to connect to access database and call tables and queries.

```
string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " + filePath;
string query = "Select * from table";
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connect);
```

However, I am struggling to find any information about calling function in the access database from Asp.net.

Is it even possibe to ms access functions from outside of  ms office applications? Asp.net or any other web service?

Comment: The data access library is ADO.NET, not ASP.NET. `OleDbCommand` is an ADO.NET class. Office applications use OLE DB to connect too.

Comment: If you're talking about a query in Access then I think you can call it like a stored procedure in a proper database. If you're talking about a macro then that's something else entirely.

Comment: How would you call a function in Access itself? What SQL query would you write? That's what you need to use here as well.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add an example of your "function" inside the Access database and explain what do you expect to see on the NET side when you call it

Comment: The function in ms access that I am trying to call does lots of calculations and stores results to Access local tables . 
I am trying to call the access calculations function and return results as a short term fix until the access application can be newly redesigned in new web application (which might take very long time to create)
I will also need to pass in parameters to call function

Comment: Being vague as your comment above I can only suggest to create a query in access that calls your function and returns your data. Then call that query from NET

Comment: Thanks for replies.
The Function has a part number parameter and then using the variable  part number , each time function is called , it does lots of calculations to get the size and lengths  of assembly parts and also generates assemble part codes.
I am just trying to find out if possible to call ms access function with parameters (not call  a query) from Visual studio

Comment: See my edit to post below. I do post some code on how to call that VBA routine in Access database. But, I don't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate issues here.

You want to query/pull data from a Access table.

This is "standard" fair, and you using the oleDB provider (in most cases). In fact, the odbc provider often is a better choice. However, lets leave this issue for another day.

However, while you can use a access data file from a web site? It not all that good of choice, since you need the access data engine installed on the web server. And that OFTEN can be a real issue, since the hosting provider will not have (or even allow) installing of the Access data engine.

NOTE VERY careful the choice of words above:

I said Access data engine!!! That is the data engine that ms-access uses.

However, if you want to run/call/use/consume VBA code?

Then you will need ms-access installed on that web server. That is a WHOLE DIFFERENT ball game. While it can be a challenge to have Access data engine installed on a web server, having Access installed is a WHOLE DIFFERENT ball game. That simple not going to be allowed nor happen in most cases.

Now, you can do this on your developer computer.

but, there are SIGNIFICANT number of issues.

first up:

You have to match the bit size of MS-Access install to that of your web server. by default, your web server going to run as x64 bits. So, this means you either:

Make sure you have ms-access x64 bits installed.

or

Force your project, and the web server to run as x32 bits.

Next up:

To CALL/USE/CONSUME/RUN/ENJOY use of VBA code routines?

Then you can't just OPEN the database (using oleDB provider), but you have to create a WHOLE RUNNING instance of Access first.

When you create that instance, you ALSO have to be VERY careful, since on access startup, any start up code will run. (start up forms, VBA code). And you don't have much control over what happens when you do this!

Often, you are better off to create a stripped down version of the database and code, and ONLY include the VBA routines you call. You then use linked tables to the actual accDB data file.

Once you created a WHOLE running instance of MS-Access, then you can all VBA code routines. However, this is not thread safe, and not all that great of a idea. Be it word, excel, or Access? it tends to be a VERY bad idea to try and create a running instance of such applications from a web server. Any kind of "prompt" that pops up in those applications means you quite much doomed at that point, since from the web server and .net code, you can't click on, or answer any of those UI prompts that can often occur when launching such applications.

What I would do is take the VBA code, create a new vb.net class (stand alone). Paste in that code, and then convert the VBA code to vb.net code. They are VERY close. If you build say a recordset helper class, then you can with GREAT ease now have that same VBA code (or VERY near the same) run as vb.net code.

You then compile that class, and then add that assembly to your c# web project, and you now have the same code and logic running on your web site.

The above is the approach I recommend.

I'm pressed for time, but perhaps this evening, I'll come back and post HOW you could call/run that VBA code from the c# web application, but while possible, it is not supported, and worse in a production web server and site? You really don't have a lot of choices to ensure that a full working version of ms-access will have been licensed and installed on that web server.

***I mean, do you REALLY want to go down this road, since is is a VERY bad design decision choice. I recommend you take that code, and duplicate the logic in .net code.***

Making really "bad" design decisions here is, well really bad!!

Writing good reliable code is a huge challenge on the best of days. So, the "how" and "why" developers write good code?

They make good design decisions, so they don't wind up with flakey code. Such developers are not really better then you, but their results are better, since they avoid choosing roads that make for poor designs in the first place.

I recall reading a book about how to play the game of pool. Turns out those better players are often not better at shooting the cue ball, but they make better decisions as to where they want to palce the cue ball after a shot.

Writing code is much the same. it not that you write better, or worse code, but is the fact that you make better, or worse design decisions that you have to live with, and then attempt to debug + maintain over time. In other words, don't go down a road that will result in a VERY difficult code to run, maintain, and choices that will reduce the reliability of your code base. You can be great at writing code, but if that code is based on a poor design decision, you still then going to struggle to make such code work in a reliable fashion.

## Edit: So, working example

So, assume in ms-access, VBA, a code module with this code:

```
Public Sub ConvertCity()

    Dim rstData         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL          As String
    
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA where Active = True"
    
    Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    Do While rstData.EOF = False
    
        rstData.Edit
        rstData!City = UCase(rstData!City)
        rstData.Update
            
        rstData.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    rstData.Close
        
End Sub
```

Now, above is just a sample, but the above VBA grabs data from a table, and converts City to upper case.

Now, our asp.net markup (a button to show data, and a button to run the above VBA code).

so, this markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdShowData" runat="server" Text="Show Access data" Width="173px" 
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdShowData_Click"/>

<asp:Button ID="cmdVBA" runat="server" Text="run Access VBA code" 
    CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:25px"
    OnClick="cmdVBA_Click"
    />

<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover"
    width="50%" >

</asp:GridView>
```

And this code to load the GV with Access data

NOTE very close, we are NOT launching access, but only open the database - consume the data.

```
    protected void cmdShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB))
        {
            string strSQL =
                @"SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
                 FROM tblHotelsA
                 WHERE Active = True
                 ORDER BY HotelName";

            using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL,conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, our next markup button, that is the one that will call/run/use some VBA code in MS-Access.

That code is this:

```
protected void cmdVBA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type MSAccess = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Access.Application");
    dynamic AccessInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(MSAccess);

    // access is now running, open the database
    string sFile = @"c:\test\test444.accdb";
    AccessInstance.OpenCurrentDataBase(sFile);

    // access is now running, call VBA routine
    AccessInstance.run("ConvertCity");  // Call VBA in a public module
    // AccessInstance.run("ConvertCity");  // Call some more VBA - walk the dog. do payroll
    AccessInstance.Quit();              // you MUST quit/shut down Access

}
```

So, when we run above web page, we see/get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Albert for effort you made helping me. I really appreciate it . But I think you gone a bit off tract for what I require, and I probably didn’t explain my requirements too well.

Comment: I have ms access database with a lot of information that needs to be re-designed in new web based application to store results in Oracle tables. We are moving away from using ms Access as front end application going forward .
As short term fix I wanted to call the code in ms access ( thousands of calculations are currently in ms access module functions and as will take months to create new calculations  in different programming languages , and then store results in  Oracle tables.

Comment: I Planned call  web service to ms access from visual studio and return results maybe using Json . To get calculations from ms access I need to pass in variable part number parameter to get calculations to return 
The only solution the past week and all I could find was the OleDbConnection to connect into ms access tables from visual studio . This is no what I require as I need to pass parameter to ms access and get return results from calling a function , this is where I am struggling for solution ? as I cant find any way to call ms access function , do some computations and return results

Comment: The example code runs that vba, and the call format supports passing parameters.  However that does not return values. However one should be able to return values.  So posted example calls a vba sub. It would be better to have access pass values to .net . I'll see if a function can be used- not sure but should be possible

Comment: Thanks again Albert for your helpfulness, however I’m getting a Null error for 

Type MSAccess = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Access.Application");
 dynamic AccessInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(MSAccess);

Comment: And are you forcing your project and web site to run as x32 bits, or x64 bits? Remember, when you create a running instance of ms-access, it HAS to match the bit size of the in-process running .net code. So, either you force your .net project (and use web site settings, and force that to run as a x32 bits process, or you install access x64 bits. You can't mix and match DIFFERNET processes in .net that are x32 bits, and x64 bits - they must match. And if ms-access is x64 bits, then DO NOT use ANY cpu, but again force the project to run as x64 bits. Remember, ms-access is "un-managed" code

Comment: Thanks Albert but I still cannot get this to work ,  Type MSAccess = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Access.Application"); is always returning Null.
I have 32 bit Access and forced project to 32 bit . The ms-access part of this functionality is ok , I just cannot call the function or Macro from Visual studio

Comment: Term function, macro and sub have specific meanings here. (ALL are different and are VERY precise terms have to be used here).  We assume you are going to call a VBA "sub" routine (not a macro). And that VBA code is NOT a function, but a sub. And that VBA Sub MUST be public, and must be in a standard code module in that application (the code can't be say in a form). Create blank new database, and use the above example.  And full access has to be installed here, not access runtime, and not just ACE/jet data engine. Verify that ms-access launches and works on that computer with the web server

Comment: Thanks Albert for all your help , only getting back to working on again this today as busy with other work, I finally got this working , error was to do with Interop Access Reference properties (Embed Interop Types needed to be set to false), Although after some testing I don’t think this solution will work for me as I will need ms access to run in background not opening an instance , so I will need a runtime engine version ms access, thanks again for help

Comment: runtime version of access is 100% identical concept. Only difference is one would be using GetObject as opposed to create object. So, using runtime version of access does not change this, but only means one has to use GetObject in place of create object.  So, the issue then becomes to deal with this being thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Albert , I had this working on localhost on my PC , but when i publish this now, Im getting error at  dynamic AccessInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(MSAccess);.  = cannot create object
I am using IIS windows server 2012 to publish. would you have any ideas why works on local host and not whe n published ?

Comment: what would GetObject be ? instead of CreateObject as I tihnk it might have something to do with runtime engine on windows server casuing this issue

Comment: Well, you have to ensure that the web server is running as x32 (assuming access x32). And create object does not work for the runtime (so, a get running object can work - but then it assumes Access is already running). And on top of that, you may well have permission rights, since app pool often can't just run programs like office. So, runtime will not work here (with create object, but CAN with get object). You can shell out and start a instance of ms-access, and then in place of create object, use get object.  You need a test server to try this stuff

Comment: you cannot use opendatabase method of the runtime, since runtime does not allow a access instance to be created and THEN open a database (it has to be supplied on the command line by using msaccess.exe and  not with com object automation).  So, access will have to been started already, and getobject has to be used (the equivalient of vb.net GetObject. I not done this, but CreateObject of ms-access don't work with runtime edition.

Comment: here is the c# equivlant of vb.net GetObject. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_GetActiveObject_System_String_

Comment: Thanks for your help Albert , I was thinking runtime was the issue. Thanks for confirming this.